# Setting elapsed time and using toString

Tags: java

I want to create a Date object, set its elapsed time to 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000, 10000000000, and 100000000000 milliseconds, and display the date and time using the toString() method.
But I am not sure how to create a for loop that manages with the increasing milliseconds value?

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Date {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long i = 0;
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(i);
            date.setTime(i);

        for (i = 1000; i < 100000000000L; i *= 10) {


            System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + i + " milliseconds");

        }
        System.out.println("Date and time: " + date.toString());

        }


    }
```

Comment: Thea actual question is unclear, please re-phrase it

Comment: You have made a loop over 10000, 100000, etc.  Did you intend to ask another question about what to do with your `date` and the `i` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your date and toString into the for loop

```
    long i = 0;
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(i);


    for (i = 1000; i < 100000000000L; i *= 10) {
        date.setTime(i);

        System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + i + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println("Date and time: " + date.toString());
    }


    }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was missing. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Date; // 1

class FoobarTimeMachine {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date; // 2
    for(long i = 1000l; i <= 100000000000l; i *= 10) { // 3
      System.out.println("Time elapsed since epoch: " + i + " milliseconds");
      date = new Date(i); // 4
      System.out.println("Corresponding date: " + date); // 5
    }
  }
}
```

Comments:

1. We're importing `java.util.Date` so we can use it later as `Date`.
2. We're not initialising the date right now, it's not needed.
3. With `<=` so we can reach 100 000 000 000.
4. Here we are initialising the date.
5. `someString + someObject` => `someString + someObject.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

you can do as :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long i = 0;
        Date d=new Date(i);

        for (i = 1000; i < 100000000000L; i *= 10) {
           System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + i + " milliseconds"); 
           d.setTime(i);
           System.out.println("Date and time: " + d.toString());
        }


}
```